# How can i prevent a child process to NOT become a zombie if parent exits

Tags: c, linux

My main process spawns a child process. If the main process is killed, the child would be assigned ppid of 1. When the child exits, it would become a zombie as init has not called wait() on this child. Is there a way to avoid this situation?

Comment: Caused by failure by the parent to wait, not caused by the parent exiting prematurely.  Absolutely correct +1 to the anser given

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`init` *will* call `wait()` on processes that it inherits. Zombies should only exist where the child has exited but the parent is still around, but is yet to reap the exit code. From the `init` manpage:

> `init` is the parent of all processes on the system, it is executed by the kernel and is responsible for starting all other processes; it is the parent of all processes whose natural parents have died and *it is responsible for reaping those when they die.*

You should make a distinction between orphans (they're still alive, their parent is dead and hence they've been adopted by `init`), and zombies (they're dead but their parent is alive and has not yet reaped them).

Orphans will become zombies for a very short period of time after they exit but before `init` reaps them but this period should be small enough that no-one notices. In fact, *all* exiting processes (except possibly `init` itself) go through this short zombie phase, it's only those cases where the parent doesn't reap quickly enough that you notice.

---

The actual code in the `init` child death (`SIGCHLD`) handler goes something like this (my comments):

```
void chld_handler (int sig) {
    CHILD  *ch;
    int    pid, st;
    int    saved_errno = errno;

    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &st, WNOHANG)) != 0) { // << WAIT done here
        if (errno == ECHILD) break;
        for (ch = family; ch; ch = ch->next) {
            if (ch->pid == pid && (ch->flags & RUNNING)) {
                INITDBG (L_VB, child_handler: marked %d as zombie", ch->pid);
                ADDSET (got_signals, SIGCHLD);
                ch->exstat = st;
                ch->flags |= ZOMBIE;                 // Set to zombie here.
                if (ch->new) {
                    ch->new->exstat = st;
                    ch->new->flags |= ZOMBIE;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ch == NULL) {
            INITDBG (L_VB, "chld_handler: unknown child %d exited.", pid);
        }
    }
    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

And then, later on in the main loop (not signal handler), any processes in the process table marked as `ZOMBIE` are cleaned up:

```
if (ISMEMBER (got_signals, SIGCHLD)) {
    INITDBG(L_VB, "got SIGCHLD");
    /* First set flag to 0 */
    DELSET(got_signals, SIGCHLD);

    /* See which child this was */
    for (ch = family; ch; ch = ch->next) {
        if (ch->flags & ZOMBIE) {                    // ZOMBIE detected here
            INITDBG (L_VB, "Child died, PID= %d", ch->pid);
            ch->flags &= ~(RUNNING|ZOMBIE|WAITING);  // And cleared here.
            if (ch->process[0] != '+') {
                write_utmp_wtmp ("", ch->id, ch->pid, DEAD_PROCESS, NULL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I disagree with the statement "orphans may become zombies".  All processes that terminate become zombies; there is no *may* about it.  The children of well behaved processes are zombies for a very short time, but they all become zombies before they are waited on by their parent.

Comment: Absolutely correct, @William, I've changed the wording to hopefully make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Put one **wait(NULL)** statement at last of program so parent and child are waiting for each other until they both completes its execution and from both anyone is not become zombie process.