# How to avoid defunct processes with python fork?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3 I am creating forked child processes, which I exit - I think - correctly. Here is some code example:

```
import os

child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    print("I am in the child with PID "+str(os.getpid()))
    # doing something
    a = 1+1
    print("Ending child with PID "+str(os.getpid()))
    os._exit(0)
else:   
    #parent process      
    os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
    import time
    for x in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("waiting...")
```

Now, as the child process seems to be ended, it still can be seen as a 'defunct' process (while the parent process is still running). How to really get rid of that ended child process? How to change the code?

Comment: By defunct do you mean it's a zombie process? Your parent needs to wait on the child to get it's exist status, then it will go away. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870945/how-can-i-prevent-a-child-process-to-not-become-a-zombie-if-parent-exits

Comment: Replacing `os._exit(0)` by `sys.exit(0)` does not change the situation. And adding a command `os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)` in the parent process does not change the situation. A 'defunct' process still exists!

Comment: @pcarter: See my command, your suggestion does not seem to work ...

Comment: You can't use `WNOHANG`. That returns immediately even if the child hasn't already exited. You have to do a `wait` that doesn't return until the child does exit and gives you the child's exit code.

Comment: So the parent process has to wait until the child finishes?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the  double fork idiom if you don't want the parent to wait. (See [What is the reason for performing a double fork when creating a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon))

The basic idea is for the parent process (call it `P`) to fork a child (`C1`) that immediately forks again to create another child (`C2`) and then exits. In this case, since the parent of `C2` is dead, the `init` process will inherit `C2` and wait on it for you. You will still have to wait on `C1` in the `P` process or `C1` will be a zombie. However, `C1` only runs for a very short time, so the `P` process will not wait long. Your code running `C2` can then take as much time as it wants and doesn't care if it finishes before or after `P`.

Another idea is to handle the SIGCHILD signal that occurs when a child has exited. From https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-December/026748.html

```
import os,signal

def handleSIGCHLD():
  os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, handleSIGCHLD)
```